# SQL create domain in apache derby

Tags: sql, derby

So I'm trying to create a basic domain in Apache derby and I'm pretty sure I have the syntax right as I have reference multiple documents on the subject. Here is what I'm inputting

```
create domain Weight float not null check (weight >=5 or <= 10);`
```

I've even tried it basically;

```
create domain Weight float
```

Is there something I'm missing with Apache Derby, I'm getting this error:

`ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "domain" at line 1, column 8.`

Any Idea why it's giving me this error, I think there might be different syntax in derby but I'm not sure.

Comment: According to the manual: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/crefsqlj95081.html  Derby does not have a `CREATE DOMAIN` statement. Why do you think that syntax should work?

Comment: Indeed, CREATE DOMAIN is vendor-specific, not standard SQL. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992734/create-domain-which-sql-does-this-syntax-exists

Comment: @BryanPendleton: `CREATE DOMAIN` is standard SQL, see ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E) 11.34 <domain definition>

Comment: Ah, thanks @LukasEder good to know. Seems like it would be a good enhancement request that it could be added to Derby, then.